# Connection to TFS Leads to Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation Error

Tags: visual-studio

I have VS.NET 2013 Ultimate with TFS 2013.  Recently, my connection to TFS was disrupted but is now back.  This resulted in a solution of mine going offline.  When I tried to get the solution online by right-clicking on it and selecting "Go online", VS.NET gives this error:

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

I know this error can happen if the length of the environment Path variable exceeds 2048, but mine is well below that.

Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has the same problem, I fixed it by going into control panel and repairing VS.NET under programs.